# workaround for magic quotes Gpc in php

Tags: php, regex

The servers have magic quotes on and it cannot be turned off for some reason.....now stripslashes would remove all the slashes added by magic quotes,but if user has put slashes in the input field(we are allowing slashes), the stripslashes would remove that as well.

I am trying for a regex which would remove the slashes only if it is preceded by {',",}....

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your question should be how to turn off magic quotes

Comment: no..i don't want to turn it off.....rather i cannot..with magic quotes on, i want the original input...hope u get what m trying to say

Comment: *"...stripslashes **would** remove that as well"*...? Are you assuming, or have you tried?

Comment: It shouldn't, since those slashes would be double-escaped. It's the officially suggested way to deal with forced magic quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: yes it do not......i should have verified before posting...my apologies....thanks all for ur comments

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in config file:

```
// remove slashes, if they are being automatically added
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc () ) {
    $_GET    = array_map('stripslashes', $_GET);
    $_POST   = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes', $_REQUEST); // see ThiefMaster's comment
}
```

That's the only place where I have to worry about slashes. In all other places I can safely assume that there are no "magic quotes".

Though, `stripslashes()` does not work with arrays, so if you expect to have arrays as values in $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE (in public web pages/systems, you DO expect to have arrays), this function might be used as a callback:

```
function stripslashes_recursive($value) {
    if ( is_array($value) ) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $value);
    }
    return stripslashes($value);
}
```

---

PHP 5.3 users might use a closure as a callback:

```
$stripslashes = function($value) use(&$stripslashes) {
    if ( is_array($value) ) {
        return array_map($stripslashes, $value);
    }
    return stripslashes($value);
};
```

This won't pollute a global scope with additional function (`stripslashes_recursive()`).

Comment: @ThiefMaster, not really, I never use $_REQUEST array. Though, if others use it, they should include it too.

Comment: @binaryLV: "if you expect to have arrays as values" Wouldn't it be best, if this were in a config file, to expect the unexpected and just run the mapping function?

Comment: Well if you ever use it you might not expect it to be still slashed. ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, what do you mean?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, depends. As I wrote, if it's public system, you *always* expect to have arrays there - so for most people that's not a question.

Comment: It must be late; for some reason, that's not making any sense to me right now. :\